# jsonlite for R gives error when trying to install

Tags: r, jsonlite

Where does one get jsonlite?  Apparently it is missing from CRAN?

```
> install.packages('jsonlite')
```

Gives:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cbusch/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/jsonlite_0.9.20.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/jsonlite_0.9.20.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/jsonlite_0.9.20.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘jsonlite’ failed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this ....`install.packages('jsonlite', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

Comment: I found this was the case for failure when trying to use RMarkdown in RStudio ("upgrade `rmarkdown`") for the first time. Installing `jsonlite` manually resolved these issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like [@user5249203 said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249203/user5249203):

`install.packages('jsonlite', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

Comment: Why does this work?  How is this different from `install.pacakges('jsonlite')`?

Comment: @avh Possibly because repos uses `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: Don't use this. It just forcibly installs the dependencies and will overwrite your currently installed libraries without asking, and then still throws the same compiler error.